# Projective representation of braid group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, braid-groups

The representation theory of braid group $B_n$ is tough, not to mention the projective representation. But my problem is simpler: how to find out all the **one-dimensional projective** representations of braid group?

Comment: There aren't any interesting one-dimensional projective representations: $\text{PGL}_1(k)$ is the trivial group.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you for your reply! Could you please explain more? My major is physics, and I'm not that familiar with the mathematics behind the projective representation. I would appreciate it if you can also give me some references.

Comment: I was interpreting the question to mean actions on $\mathbb{P}^1$, i.e., maps to $\mathrm{PGL}_2$. @Tengen, concretely, are you asking for two by two matrices (up to scalars)?

Comment: @Tengen: an $n$-dimensional projective representation of a group $G$ is a homomorphism $G \to \text{PGL}_n(k)$, where one definition of $\text{PGL}_n(k)$ is that it is the quotient of $\text{GL}_n(k)$ by the subgroup of diagonal matrices. When $n = 1$, $\text{GL}_1(k)$ *is* its subgroup of diagonal matrices, so the quotient is trivial. A morphism into $\text{PGL}_2(k)$ is a $2$-dimensional projective representation.